# Гибкое содержимое на Symfony

Tags: symfony

Ищу способ реализации гибкого содержимого на Symfony по аналогии с flexible content из acf вордпресса. Т.е. по принципу конструктора страницы из готовых (предварительно написанных) блоков/виджетов. Может быть, есть какие-то готовые решения или хотя бы примерное направление, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Копайте в сторону хранения шаблонов в базе данных.

Comment: Шаблоны блоков имеет смысл хранить в обычных файлах, как везде. Поля - да, понятно, что в БД. Странно, что нет готового решения ни в симфони, ни в yii2 (в ларавеле, значит, наверняка тоже подобного нет). Похоже, придется ваять собственный компонент.

Comment: Наверное бандл, не компонент.